# Is it valid to calculate Berry phase when there is energy level crossing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Assume that we have electronic band structure and want to calculate Berry phase following the red line:

[image]

If we have energy crossing in the path of integration, is it okay just to use the Berry phase formula

$$  \gamma_n = i\oint \langle u_{red band} | \bigtriangledown_k |u_{red band}\rangle dk ~~? $$ 
Since adiabatic theorem assumes no degeneracy of energy, I'm not sure if this integration is valid.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't, because of crossing. Please have a look on this [Topological properties of Berry's phase](https://128.84.21.199/pdf/quant-ph/0411006v2.pdf). May be of some help to you.

Comment: This is another of great help. [Entanglement, Berry Phases, and Level Crossings for the Atomic
Breit-Rabi Hamiltonian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.2912.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In case of degeneracy, one has to approach to the problem in a different way. I find some useful references. These might be useful in the case you are considering. Berry phase effects on electronic properties, Rev. Mod. Phys. 82, 1959 (2010), Sec. 2, Phys. Rev. Lett. 52, 2111 (1984), Phys. Rev. B 72, 085110 (2005).
I myself have never performed such calculations. My guess is that at the degeneracy point, the Berry phase is not uniquely defined as there are two directions at the that point.